# Variance of sum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Suppose  $Y=\sum_i X_i$, where $X_i$ random variable and independent with pdf  $f(x)$
Find the pdf of $Y$ and compute $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do we know anything about $x_1,x_2,\ldots$? Are they random?

Comment: Yes, they are all random. I have just edited the problem

Comment: Are the $X_i$'s independent? And are you sure $f$ is their pdf, and not their cdf? (if not, what exactly is the range of values $X_i$ can take? The pdf you give does not sum to $1$)

Comment: $f$ is pdf, and $X_i\in [0;1]$

Comment: Then it is not a valid pdf: [a pdf should sum to $1$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F(1%2Be%5E-x)%2C%20x%3D0..1&t=crmtb01)

Comment: I got a mistakes, $X_i\in [-inf, +inf]$ and $f$ is cdf like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Comment: This is the cdf, not pdf, then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution (otherwise, the function has an infinite sum, clearly not $1$ either: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f = \infty$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Clement pointed out, the the sigmoid function is not a valid pdf because its integral is not equal to $1$. I am almost certain that you mean that it is the cdf, as it is a nondecreasing function that tends to $0$ and $1$ as $x$ tends to $-\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively.

Hints: In general, $E[Y]=E\left[\sum_i X_i\right] = \sum_i E[X_i]$. If the $X_i$ are also independent, then $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_i X_i\right) = \sum_i \operatorname{Var}(X_i)$.

Comment: While I agree with the general statements you make about expectation and variance, I'm puzzled by the first step -- before giving a hint to solve the question, it'd help to have the question (and right now it's not clear, at least to me, how the $X_i$'s are even defined)

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you for catching the typo.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me the value of $E(X_i)$ and $Var(X_i)$?

Comment: You have $X_i$ following a logistic distribution with parameter $\mu=0$, $s=1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution The expectation is $\mu=0$, the variance $s^2\frac{\pi^2}{3}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$.